# Multiplying with parenthesis result using overloaded * operator in C++

Tags: c++, vector, overloading, parentheses

So I've been writing a small math library in C++ and when dealing with a scalar multiplied by a vector I get some issues when I try to perform this operation

```
Vect V2;
Vect V3;
float S;

Vect V1 = V2 + S * (V2 - V3);
```

The Vect Value I receive in the overloaded operator * is a new Vect object and not the outcome of the (V2 - V3) part of the operation. Here's the other relevant part of the code. If I follow the operation with the debugging the two overloaded operators work correctly by themselves but not one after the other.

Vect.h

```
Vect &operator - (const Vect &inVect);
friend const Vect operator*(const float scale, const Vect &inVect);
```

Vect.cpp

```
Vect &Vect::operator - (const Vect &inVect)
{
    return Vect (this->x - inVect.x,this->y - inVect.y,this->z - inVect.z, 1);
}

const Vect operator*(const float scale, const Vect &inVect)
{
    Vect result;

    result.x = InVect.x * scale;
    result.z = InVect.y * scale;
    result.y = InVect.z * scale;
    result.w = 1;

    return result;
}
```

I also overloaded the + and = operator and they work as expected the only problem I encounter is the problem above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `operator-`, you create a temporary `Vect` and return a reference to that temporary. The temporary is destroyed at the end of the `return` statement and the returned reference is left dangling. Doing anything with this reference will result in undefined behaviour.

Instead, your `operator-` should return a `Vect` by value:

```
Vect Vect::operator - (const Vect &inVect)
{
  return Vect (this->x - inVect.x,this->y - inVect.y,this->z - inVect.z, 1);
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, I've been working on it for hours and didn't notice it... I seriously need a break... Thanks a lot mate, really helpful.

Comment: @user2057043: **turn on your compiler warnings**! Nobody expects you to spot that tiny `&`, but your compiler should, and probably has ways to report it.